# Aspire One battery compatibility

Tags: battery, netbook, compatibility

I'm definitely unsatisfied with battery life in my Acer Aspire One D270.

Probably buying an extended battery would be completely satisfactory, and I have a semi-local vendor who has some definitely competitive prices on reasonable quality replacements. The problem is, D270 is quite new and not present in their catalog yet, although they have quite a few batteries for other Aspire One netbooks, and they seem similar enough that I'm willing to bet at least some would work with mine.

So I'm asking for info on interchangeability of batteries between D270 and other Aspire One netbooks - what models of battery / batteries for which netbook models can I buy that would work with it?

(the stock battery I have is AL10A31, 11.1V 2.12Ah)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this website, the following are compatible. Further research would help - or alternatively, you could find pictures of the battery for another model from this list and see if they're the same.

Acer AL10A31 Battery will fit models:

ACER
Acer Aspire One 360 (D260), 
Acer Aspire One 522, 
Acer Aspire One 722,
Acer Aspire One D270,
Acer Aspire One E100

Acer Aspire One AOD255 Series
Aspire One AOD255, Aspire One AOD255-A01B/B, 
Aspire One AOD255-A01B/K, Aspire One AOD255-A01B/W

Acer Aspire One D255 Series
Aspire One D255, Aspire One D255-1134,
Aspire One D255-1203, Aspire One D255-1268, 
Aspire One D255-1549, Aspire One D255-1625, 
Aspire One D255-2107, Aspire One D255-2136,
Aspire One D255-2184, Aspire One D255-2256, 
Aspire One D255-2301, Aspire One D255-2331, 
Aspire One D255-2333, Aspire One D255-2509,
Aspire One D255-2520, Aspire One D255-2532, 
Aspire One D255-2583, Aspire One D255-2640, 
Aspire One D255-2670, Aspire One D255-2691,
Aspire One D255-2795, Aspire One D255-2929, 
Aspire One D255-2934, Aspire One D255-2981, 
Aspire One D255-2BQ, Aspire One D255E, 
Aspire One D255-N55DQ

Acer Aspire One D257 Series
Aspire One D257, Aspire One D257E

Acer Aspire One D260 Series
Aspire One D260, Aspire One D260-2028, 
Aspire One D260-2097, Aspire One D260-2203, 
Aspire One D260-2207, Aspire One D260-2344,
Aspire One D260-2365, Aspire One D260-23797, 
Aspire One D260-2380, Aspire One D260-2440, 
Aspire One D260-2455, Aspire One D260-2571,
Aspire One D260-2576, Aspire One D260-2680, 
Aspire One D260-2919, Aspire One D260-2Bkk, 
Aspire One D260-2Bp, Aspire One D260-2BQGkk_XP616 3G,
Aspire One D260-2BQGss_XP616 3G, Aspire One D260-2BQkk_XP316,
Aspire One D260-2BQpu_XP316, Aspire One D260-2BQss_XP316,
Aspire One D260-2DQkk_W7625, Aspire One D260-2DQpu_W7625,
Aspire One D260-2DQss_W7625, Aspire One D260-2DQuu_W7625,
Aspire One D260-N51B/K, Aspire One D260-N51B/KF, 
Aspire One D260-N51B/M, Aspire One D260-N51B/P, 
Aspire One D260-N51B/S, Aspire One D260-N51B/SF

Acer Aspire One happy Series
Aspire One happy, Aspire One happy2

http://accessory-acer-laptop.com/al10a31.htm